# How to merge multiple Eloquent relations?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.4 to return tasks that a person has created or is managing.

The code is as follow:

```
public function tasks()
{
    $creator = $this->morphMany('App\Task', 'created_by');
    $manager = $this->morphMany('App\Task', 'managed_by');
}
```

This function is expected to return an object of type `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`.

I tried these two attempts, but NONE of them returns the required type:

```
// using merge:
$task1 = collect([$creator]);
$task2 = collect([$manager]);

return $task1->merge($task2); // it returns an empty collection.
```

2nd attempt using query builder:

```
return Task::
    where([
        ['created_by_type', '=', 'App\Person'],
        ['created_by_id', '=', $this->id]
    ])
    ->orwhere([
        ['managed_by_type', '=', 'App\Person'],
        ['managed_by_id', '=', $this->id]
    ])->get();
// returns the correct data but not as an object of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

Is it possible to merge these two relations and return the result as `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` type?

Comment: What is the reason you need the type relation returned?

Comment: too many reasons to list them all here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's not possible (for now).

Comment: I've created a package for merging relationships: https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-merged-relations

Answer (score 1):

While it may be possible to make some sort of hack or use a package, I think you're best bet would be to rethink your table structure a little bit. From what I gather from your posts you have:

```
Persons
  id
  other_data
```

and

```
Task
  managed_by_type
  managed_by_id
  created_by_type
  created_by_id
  other_data
```

if you swapped to:

```
Person
  id
  other_data

Task
  id
  other_data

Person_Task
  owner_id
  owner_type
  task_id
  type // managed or created (int)
```

You would have a more flexible solution going forward.

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Task', 'owner', 'persons_tasks');
}

public function createdTasks()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Task', 'owner', 'persons_tasks')->withPivot('type')->where('type', 0);
}

public function managedTasks()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Task', 'owner', 'persons_tasks')->withPivot('type')->where('type', 1);
}
```

Comment: cool alternative. thank you. I will consider it.
but I'll wait to think of an alternative until I get an answer to this question: if it's possible to merge multiple Eloquent relations? and get the result as eloquent relation type.

?